# How to change the color of a single character in a String with drawString?

Tags: java, graphics, colors, awt, java-2d

I have a question in using `drawString()`. I'm creating a game like [zType](http://www.phoboslab.org/ztype/) and I have this problem with `drawString()`. How can I change the font color of a character in a `drawString()` while it's moving?

Comment: @peeskillet  Unless this question is closed as 'Read The Fine Manual', that should be an answer.

Comment: Not the whole string..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that you've made it clear that you want to draw only some characters of a string in a particular color (which is an important detail that should be mentioned in your question), you can, as others have mentioned, calculate the font metrics yourself for those characters.

But there can be more to drawing a single contiguous string than just FontMetrics, such as kerning and even connecting letters in certain scripts and fonts.  Instead, I would use an AttributedCharacterIterator.

The easiest way to get an AttributedCharacterIterator is to create an [`AttributedString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/AttributedString.html):

```
AttributedString a = new AttributedString(text);

// We want first two characters drawn in red.
a.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.RED, 0, 2);

graphics.drawString(a.getIterator(), x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call Graphics.setColor() as shown below,

```
public void paint (Graphics g) {
   g.setColor(Color.RED);
   g.drawString("Hello World!!", 50, 100);
}
```

If you want only the first character to be in different color, then you should be doing something like this,

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
   Color prev = g.getColor();
   g.setColor(Color.RED);
   g.drawString("H", 50, 100);
   FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics();
   int width = metrics.stringWidth("H");
   g.setColor(prev);
   g.drawString("ello World!!", 50 + width, 100);
}
```

Comment: Not the whole String. just the 'H' in "Hello World"

Comment: Then you should use two drawString calls. One to just draw the first character.. measure the pixel width or height of the first character rendered. offset this width or height in the next drawString() call.

Comment: I have added some code to change the color of only the first character. Please check if it meets your needs. If it is OK, you could wrap it up in your own method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `FontMetrics` to get the width of the `H` and add that width to the `x` point of `ello`

```
    Font font = new Font("impact", Font.PLAIN, 50);
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(font);
    int widthH = fm.stringWidth("H");
    g.setFont(font);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawString("H", 100, 100);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawString("ello", 100 + widthH, 100);
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestHColor extends JPanel {


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Font font = new Font("impact", Font.PLAIN, 50);
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(font);
        int widthH = fm.stringWidth("H");
        g.setFont(font);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawString("H", 100, 100);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("ello", 100 + widthH, 100);
    }

    @Override 
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello String");
                frame.add(new TestHColor());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```